# Weak High E (1st String) on Electric Guitar, any remedy?

Tags: electric-guitar, technique, strings

I have a Samick Electric Guitar that's relatively an inexpensive copy of Strat. It plays all right and suits me as a beginner.

However I specifically notice that the High E (1st string) sounds weak as compared to other 5. So there's is unintended variation in the volume when I switch to 1st string.

So far I have tried lowering the action on 1st string and also raising that side of pickup height. However there's no much difference. One more thing I wish to give it a try is to replace only the first string with relatively medium gauge string (Current ones are all thin) and check.

Is this a problem with the instrument or expected variation and is there any possible solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way for my money to see if there is actually a problem in the way that end of the pickup is picking up the string sound by my reckoning would be to be a scientist about it: buy two plain b strings, and fit them both to the 1st and 2nd string position of the guitar.  Then you have a controlled comparison.  If there's a noticeable volume difference then there's a problem with your pups or your setup.  If there isn't, then it was a problem with your old strings being unbalanced: buy a new set.

A single plain .12/.13 Ernie ball or Rotosound or something will set you back a dollar or less, it's worth it in my book to effectively work out what's going on.

This won't have any effect on neck tension etc. if you're worried about that.